# What is the correct way to rename a signed, zip-aligned .apk file?

Tags: android, apk

I use an app when developing for android that takes care of all the signing and zip aligning for me, however when it is finished all the apks end up with the same name. Now I know that it doesn't really matter as google play renames the apk anyway, but I want to be able to tell the apks apart when storing them locally and still have them as valid signed/aligned apks. So I guess my question is can I just rename them using windows explorer or do I need a special tool to rename them correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I've just been using standard file managers (Mac OS Finder/unix mv) to rename my APKs. Haven't run into any issues so far. I think that the Google Play developer console just ignores the filename for all practical purposes, which is how it should be.

The signing and zip-aligning are thinks that happen to the file *data*. The filename is part of the file's *metadata* which is stored seperately by the filesystem of your OS. If you edit a file's *metadata* it shouldn't result in a change to the *data* - and if it does, there's a bug in your file manager!

What the Google Play developer console **does** care about is the manifest in the apk, though!